# How to export Android Profiler CPU usage

Tags: android, android-studio, cpu, profiler, android-profiler

Is there a method to export this cpu % usage to file, where can i for ex. measure the mean % cpu usage?

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKgVG.png)

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: @NuPagadi I have read whole documentation, but there is nothing about it. They Only mention, that i can take .trace file, but i think that trivial info about percentage usage of CPU - is not there - there can be more complex information about threads, methods etc. What i need that is take out this data from profiler and log it somewhere, where can i calculate the mean % usage of CPU that moment in time for example ... Now my only way is manualy write this data into .xls, but that is so bad ...